# Missing the end of the XML when serializing with DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I have the following method that I use to serialize various objects to XML. I then write the XML to a file. All the objects have the proper `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes.

```
    public static string Serialize<T>(T item)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));

        using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(builder))
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(xmlWriter, item);
            return builder.ToString();
        }
    }
```

The serialization works fine, however, I am missing the end of the content. I.e., the string does not contain the full XML document: the end gets truncated. Sometimes the string ends right in the middle of a tag.

There does not seem to be a miximum length that would cause an issue: I have strings of 18k that are incomplete and I have strings of 80k that are incomplete as well.

The XML structure is fairly simple and only about 6-8 nodes deep.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`xmlWriter` isn't flushed at the point you call `ToString()`; try:

```
    using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(builder))
    {
        serializer.WriteObject(xmlWriter, item);
    }
    return builder.ToString();
```

This does the `ToString()` *after* the `Dispose()` on `xmlWriter`, meaning it will flush any buffered data to the output (`builder` in this case).